# What kind of adapter have I to use here? Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Here is xml activity file

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="309dp"
        android:layout_height="677dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="164dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.72"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is Adapter Creator:

```
adapter = new myAdapter(dataholder);
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here I get new adapter.

```
ArrayList<Model> dataholder = new ArrayList<Model>();
myAdapter adapter;
```

And here I get this error, idk what does it mean.

```
'setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(myAdapter)'
```

Here is Model Class, I need it to create new Reminder and put it in RecyclerView.

```
package com.example.kanlane.reminder;

public class Model {
    String title, date, time;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(String title, String date, String time) {
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTitle() {

        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {

        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {

        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {

        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {

        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

I don't know what this error means, help me please.

---

I tried to use this:

```
ArrayList<Model> dataholder = new ArrayList<Model>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
```

And this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(dataholder);
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(java.util.ArrayList<com.example.kanlane.reminder.Model>)
```

And this:

```
'setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(android.widget.ArrayAdapter)
```

Comment: From the error I can say that your `myadapter` class does not extend the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class. You must extend your adapter class from `RecyclerView.Adapter` to be able to use with the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: The [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) shows you how to create a recycler view adapter

Comment: myAdapter is just an example, I wanna know which (ArrayAdapter or smth else) I have to use instead of ```myAdapter```

Comment: @RickyMo I have to create new class?

Comment: You can create a new class extend the `RecyclerView.Adapater` or make use of `ArrayAdapter`, use whatever suit your needs.

Comment: @RickyMo I think it will be easier to make ArrayAdapter, I will try right now.

Comment: @RickyMo I tried it, but I still have problems, I updated the question, help me please.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up. `ArrayAdapter` is for `ListView` but not `RecyclerView`. You have to create a new class extending `RecyclerView.Adapter` according to the guide.

Comment: @RickyMo can you help me with it? i'm a newbie((
Write this class as an answer

Comment: You can find many tutorial online on how to implement recycler view